# Recieving Illegal start of expression error in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, performance-testing

Just hoping for a bit of guidance on a code.  For the first bit (see below), I am trying to make an instance method that will pretty much add the given values. My issue is that I keep getting an illegal start of expression error. I was wondering if anybody would be able to explain why, since it looks fine to me? Keep in mind I only posted the portion of code where I am receiving an error message.

*EDIT* I actually wanted to open this question back up for a second since for whatever reason I was recieving an odd error. I was able to get the code completed but I am receiving an error message when I test it stating IllegalArgumentException: The letter chosen is invalid. Must be T, D, or E. The given data 84 will be ignored. I'm wondering why the error message is appearing since I am choosing on of those letters and I'm not using 84 as a number at all.

```
public int addNewValue ( char amtType, int amount) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount in dollars");
    amount=keyboard.nextInt();   

    System.out.println("Please select the amount Type: T-Ticket Sales,"
            + " D-Donations, E-Expenses");
    amtType=keyboard.next().charAt(0);

   if (amount<=0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount must be positive and "
               + "non-zero. The given data " +amount+ " will be ignored.");

//below is where I recieve the error message

   }else if (amtType !=T&&!=D&&!=E ) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The letter chosen is invalid."
                   + "Must be T, D, or E. The given data " +amtType+ 
                   " will be ignored");
        }else{
       return amount + amtType;
   } 
}
```

Comment: `amtType !=T|!=D|!=E ` what is it?

Comment: probably you want `if (  (amtType!='T') && (amtType!='D') && (amtType!='E') )`

Comment: @Lashane hello! essentially I wanted the user to only use the letters T, D, or E as those letters have a set value elsewhere in the code. If they did not chose that, I wanted to have an error message appear. I'm new to java so from what I understood != is the same as not equal to correct? Or is it not used in that context?

Comment: You are correct, `!=` is the not-equal operator. However `a != b | != c` is invalid syntax. You cannot chain operator like that, but must instead use two tests separated by an `&&` (and) operator, as in `a != b && a != c`, just like @Lashane said. Note that you need the *and* operator, not the *or* operator.

Comment: ahhh ok thats making more sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to write the if condition like this:

```
    }else if (amtType !='T' && amtType !='D' && amtType !='E' ) {
```

With using `&&` instead of `||` and use `'` single quote to check char.